# Is there a way to delete "wp-block-group__inner-container" div from the gutenberg editor view?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Currently I'm in the process of matching the editor style to the frontend, in order to facility page editing for unexperienced users. I have removed the "wp-block-group__inner-container" div from the front-end since it interferes with the HTML structure. The only problem is that this doesn't affect the block editor, and any styles containing grid or flex will not render correctly because of the added inner container.

Is there a way to force the editor to not output those when using groups? I would really like the editor to match the final output of the page.

Comment: Are you able give an example of the block markup that is being saved? By grouping the blocks in your layout, the surrounding `<div>` will always be added. Is there an additional editor.css stylesheet enqueued affecting the Editor?

Comment: @S.Walsh groups made in the Gutenberg editor will output an outer Div inside themselves called “inner__container”. You can remove those from the front end by adding filters in functions.php but that is not possible to achieve inside the Gutenberg editor itself. I want know if there’s a way to remove that div from the backend editor

Comment: It sounds like you are using a "classic theme" and not a block-based theme? As in the new block-based theme the "wp-block-group__inner-container" isn't added any more and this issue would not appear.

Comment: @S.Walsh I cannot change the theme of the site without extensive rework of the styling sheets and html. Though, the theme I’m using shows the block editor interface with no problem. Are you saying that while the interface is showing the block editor, the underlying structure is the classic one??

Comment: The structure saved depends on what version of WP/Gutenberg and whether your theme has theme.json. I've added a possible workaround for you to try as an answer below..

Answer (score 0):

While you could use JavaScript to remove the `wp-block-group__inner-container` div from the Editor, it will likely cause more issues in the Editor than it solves. There is an [open issue for the opposite approach](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/41124), which details that `wp-block-group__inner-container` is removed when `theme.json` is used; though depends entirely on your theme setup and if you want to make those kind of big changes.

I've experienced a very similar issue with InnerBlocks. In the Editor, InnerBlocks are wrapped in 2 extra divs - not ideal, styling break/inconsistent with front end (depending on the block). The divs enable the blocks to be reordered in the Editor but are not saved in the final markup, so I don't want to remove them. In the end, the workaround was to add additional specific CSS only for the Editor to imitate the layout of front-end, eg:

**editor.scss**

```css
.wp-block-namespace-project{
    >.block-editor-inner-blocks > .block-editor-block-list__layout{
        //  or .wp-block-group__inner-container
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex: 1 1 100%;      
  }
}
```

**style.scss** (or the main theme.css)

```css
.wp-block-namespace-project{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 100%;      
}
```

You could apply the above CSS approach with `wp-block-group__inner-container` by [adding CSS for the Editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/enqueue_editor_block_styles_assets/) without editing your main theme files/html structure.